# In Code Geass, why is the plan called the "Zero Requiem"?

Tags: code-geass

In the last episode of Code Geass, why is Lelouch’s plan called the "Zero Requiem"?

Are there any reasons why the plan is given that name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last episode of Code Geass, Lelouch's plan is called the "Zero Requiem" for several significant reasons:

[image: zero]

**Symbolism**: Lelouch takes on the persona of "Zero" throughout the series, which represents his quest for justice and his rebellion against Britannia. The name "Zero Requiem" reflects his plan to bring about a final resolution to his struggle and the world's conflicts.

[image: requiem]

**Requiem**: A requiem is a musical composition or a mass for the dead. Lelouch's plan involves sacrificing himself as part of a grand scheme to bring about peace. The use of "requiem" suggests that Lelouch's death will be a key element in his plan.

[image: sacrifice]

**Zero's Sacrifice**: Lelouch intends to become the symbol of hatred and evil in the eyes of the world, in order to unite humanity against a common enemy. By doing so, he aims to end the cycle of war and violence that has plagued the world. The name "Zero Requiem" signifies that his sacrifice is an essential part of his plan to bring about peace.

[image]

**Redemption**: Lelouch's plan is also a form of redemption for the many questionable actions he has taken throughout the series. By sacrificing himself and taking on the role of the world's greatest villain, he hopes to atone for his past deeds and create a better world for future generations.

Overall, the name "Zero Requiem" encapsulates the themes of sacrifice, redemption, and the desire for a better world that are central to Lelouch's character and his ultimate plan to bring about peace in the Code Geass universe.

Pic source: google.com

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. While this might be a thorough answer, could you [edit] and provide some references to back up the answer?